# Firestore Get: Is it useful to specify a failure listener or could we just use if(!task.isSuccessful())?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

[The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) doesn't specify a `addOnFailureListener` to the method `get`.

However, it is written::

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            ...
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
```

In particular: `get failed with` in the `Log.d` call of the `else` statement.

Does it mean that `addOnFailureListener` can be replaced by this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace a single OnCompleteListener that checks the success status of the Task with both an OnFailureListener and an OnSuccessListener that each assume that the status of the result.

This is not specific to Firestore.  This is the way that the [Play Services Task API](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks) works for all code that uses it.